# COMODO SSL Certificate on apache CentOS

Tags: android, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have deployed COMODO SSL on Apached CentOS but does not work on Android Older Versions.

I think I am missing something. I configured as below.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my_domain_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my_domain_com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

#SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I received following files in a ZIP

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
my_domain_com.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue got help from this URL.

[http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/04/04/installing-comodo-positive-ssl-certs-on-apache-and-openssl/][1]